# Using a Proc accepting a Tuple containing unions

Tags: crystal-lang

When trying to use a `Proc` with `Tuple` containing union types as an argument:

```
proc = ->(t : Tuple(Float64|Int32, Float64|Int32)){ t[0] + t[1] }
proc.call({1, 3})
```

I get this error:

> type must be Tuple(Float64 | Int32, Float64 | Int32), not Tuple(Int32, Int32)

Isn't the tuple `{1,3}` already of that type? If not, how can I pass a tuple of that type?
Or are tuples containing union types not supported when using a `Proc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to explicitly cast it for now:

```
proc = ->(t : {Float64|Int32, Float64|Int32}){ t[0] + t[1] }
proc.call({1, 3}.as({Float64|Int32, Float64|Int32}))
```

You can tidy it up a little bit with an alias:

```
alias Point = {Float64|Int32, Float64|Int32}
proc = ->(t : Point){ t[0] + t[1] }
proc.call({1, 3}.as(Point))
```

Or maybe even create a dedicated value type:

```
record Point, x : Float64|Int32, y : Float64|Int32
proc = ->(t : Point){ t.x + t.y }
proc.call(Point.new(1, 3))
```